# PlantUML osaPuml How to change standard name of icon

Tags: plantuml

I use osaPuml to generate some network diagrams. In every icon will be desplayed the real name of the icon like «osa_user_green_developer» or «osa_desktop». for unexperiented reader of the manual it's very disturbing, to see this unnessecary information.

Example:

```
@startuml

!define osaPuml https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Crashedmind/PlantUML-opensecurityarchitecture2-icons/master
!include osaPuml/Common.puml
!include osaPuml/User/all.puml
!include osaPuml/Hardware/all.puml
!include osaPuml/Misc/all.puml
!include osaPuml/Server/all.puml
!include osaPuml/Site/all.puml
' Users
osa_user_green_developer(Mary, "Mary", "Product team", "Developer")
osa_user_green_operations(Ivan, "Ivan", "IT Team", "Server Admin")
osa_user_green_business_manager(Bob, "Bob", "Accounts team", "Manager")
@enduml
```

The programming name of the icon is always shown. How can I suppress the names of the icons?

I tried to suppres or to substitute the programming name and didn't found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `hide stereotype` instruction:

```
@startuml
hide stereotype
!define osaPuml https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Crashedmind/PlantUML-opensecurityarchitecture2-icons/master
!include osaPuml/Common.puml
!include osaPuml/User/all.puml
!include osaPuml/Hardware/all.puml
!include osaPuml/Misc/all.puml
!include osaPuml/Server/all.puml
!include osaPuml/Site/all.puml
' Users
osa_user_green_developer(Mary, "Mary", "Product team", "Developer")
osa_user_green_operations(Ivan, "Ivan", "IT Team", "Server Admin")
osa_user_green_business_manager(Bob, "Bob", "Accounts team", "Manager")
@enduml
```